# Axios get request with parameter is not working

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, get, axios, postman

I am passing a parameter to the axios get request. It works on postman properly but does not work with my code. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

I want only one specific data from db but I am receiving all the data in available in the collection. But with postman I get the desired data

backend route :

```
router.get('/displayUser', (req,res) => {
  const query = user =  req.body ;
  Services.find(query)
      .exec((err, services) => res.json(services))
})
```

axios call : I tried two different ways and both didn't work

method 1:

```
getData: async function () {
      const user = this.userId
      console.log(user) 
      let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/services/displayUser' , { params: { user }})
      console.log(res.data);
}
```

method 2:

```
getData: async function () {
      var data = JSON.stringify({"user":this.userId});
      console.log(data)
      var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/services/displayUser',
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : data
      };

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

When I get the data in console I am getting all 3 objects available in collection instead of the specific one related to the user Id

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h0QN.png)

But in postman It works as desired

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMaAV.png)

Comment: Try sending the data into axios without stringifying it (ie) var data =  {"user":this.userId};

Comment: I tried doing that, still doesn't work @AmaarshallYaswankar

Comment: Ayyo, this is confusing me :( @Jayashree

Comment: I have been breaking my head with this too :'( @AmaarshallYaswankar

Comment: Kinda rare scenarios lol

Comment: Let me see if I could help

Comment: can you share the full pic of the response json from postman? I am able to see only the end part

Comment: I have edited the screenshot to show the entire object @AmaarshallYaswankar

Comment: @JayashreeK Have you tried the built-in code generation feature of Postman? You have the ability to get Axios snippets from there. More info here https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: the second method is from the built-in code feature of postman @Arlemi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this as following:

- when I need a get :

```
app.get('/detail/:id', function (req, res) {    
  //console.log(req.params.id);
  var url=urlDetail + "/" + req.params.id;
  axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
   // result=response.data;
    res.render('database', { title: 'Detail' , dbs: response.data ,Version:pjson.version});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
    //console.log("ici always");
  });
});
```

- and when i need to post (req.body is a json):

```
app.post('/carto/demande', function (req, res) {   
  let data; 
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(req.body);
  var url=urlCartoDemande;

  axios.post(url,req.body)
  .then(function (response) {


    data=response.data;
    res.render('carto',    { title : 'Demande' ,Version:pjson.version,mode:"resultat",data:data   }    );
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed

  });      
});
```